# Modular Program. Calling Functions In The Host

Tags: c#, mef

I have built a modular program using

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258681/Windows-Forms-Modular-App-using-MEF  as a base and I have several of my modules working.

It is a MDI Windows Forms application and I need to call back to the host module for some stuff.

a) Location information for the MDI host window

b) Write to the status bar in the host window.

I have managed to get the application to compile but when I call the host functions it always gives me a null exception

I did look at [Using MEF with C#, how do I call methods on the host, from the plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572647/using-mef-with-c-how-do-i-call-methods-on-the-host-from-the-plugin)

which is where I got my line

```
public Exec.Core.Interfaces.IHost Host;
```

But host is always null so I get exceptions trying to access the members of MDIForm which is the host.

Even if I do  public Exec.Core.Interfaces.IHost Host {get;set;}

This is the Host.

```
NameSpace Exec
{
  [Export(typeof(Exec.Core.Interfaces.IHost))]
   //  MDIForm is the host.    
  public partial class MDIForm : Form, Exec.Core.Interfaces.IHost
  {
     ///other stuff not related to the problem


      // defined in public interface IHost
    public Point myLocation()
    {
      return this.Location;  // need the window location

    }
      // defined in public interface IHost
    public IHost GetHost()
    {  // is this what GetHost Should Return? Not sure
      return this;
    }
      // defined in public interface IHost
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
      SetStatusBar(message); // print a message to MDIForm status bar
    }
  }
}
```

Then is the IHosts.cs

```
namespace Exec.Core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IHost
    {
        IHost GetHost();
        void SendMessage(string message);
        Point myLocation();
       // MDIForm GetThis( );  /* this gives error. Can't resolve MDIForm
                                  I don't know why and can't resolve.*/
    }
}
```

This is one of the modules where I am trying to get stuff from the host

```
namespace Exec.Modules.Tasks
{
   [Export]
   public partial class frmTasks : Form
   {
       [Import(typeof (Exec.Core.Interfaces.IHost))] 
       public Exec.Core.Interfaces.IHost Host;
           // unfortunately Host == NULL at this point

       private void SendMessage (string message)
       {
           try
           {
              Host.SendMessage(message);  <Throws System.NullReferenceException
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
           }
       }
       private IHost WhichHost()
       {
           try
           {     /// not really sure what will be returned here
               return GetHost();<Throws System.NullReferenceException
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }
       }
       private Point Location()
       {
          try
          {
             return mylocation(); <Throws  System.NullReferenceException
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
          }
       }
   }
}
```

And finally this is how I put all of the objects together in ModuleHandler.cs
This is pretty much taken from the codeproject above with some seperation of some method calls into 2 pieces so I could see why it was dying.

```
 namespace Exec.Core   
 {
     [Export(typeof(IModuleHandler))]
     public class ModuleHandler : IDisposable, IModuleHandler
     {

        [ImportMany(typeof(IModule), AllowRecomposition = true)]
         // The ModuleList will be filled with the imported modules
        public List<Lazy<IModule, IModuleAttribute>> ModuleList
        { get; set; }

        [ImportMany(typeof(IMenu), AllowRecomposition = true)]
        // The MenuList will be filled with the imported Menus
        public List<Lazy<IMenu, IModuleAttribute>> MenuList { get; set; }

        [Import(typeof(IHost))]
        // The imported host form
        public IHost Host { get; set; }


       AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
       public void InitializeModules()
       {
          // Create a new instance of ModuleList
          ModuleList = new List<Lazy<IModule, IModuleAttribute>>();
          // Create a new instance of MenuList
          MenuList = new List<Lazy<IMenu, IModuleAttribute>>();

          // Foreach path in the main app App.Config      
          foreach (var s in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys)
          {
            if (s.StartsWith("Path"))
            {
             // Create a new DirectoryCatalog with the path loaded from the App.Config
                DirectoryCatalog cataloglist = new DirectoryCatalog(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[s], "jobexe*.dll");
               catalog.Catalogs.Add(cataloglist);
             }
           }
            // Create a new catalog from the main app, to get the Host
           catalog.Catalogs.Add( new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()));
                    // Create a new catalog from the ModularWinApp.Core
            DirectoryCatalog catalogExecAssembly = new DirectoryCatalog( System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
              System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location ), "exe*.dll");

            catalog.Catalogs.Add(catalogExecAssembly);
            // Create the CompositionContainer
            CompositionContainer cc = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            try
            {
                cc.ComposeParts(this);
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
            { MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); }

            catch (ChangeRejectedException e)
            { MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); }     
        }            
    }
}
```

So again, the modules work independently but are unable to call back to the host.  Wondering what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help

One final thing that may have something to do with the issue.

Here is the code that starts the program

```
 public static ModuleHandler _modHandler = new ModuleHandler();

static void Main()
{
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

  //Initialize the modules. Now the modules will be loaded.
   _modHandler.InitializeModules();
    // this goes straight to class MDIForm()  constructor
  Application.Run(_modHandler.Host as Form);

}
```

Colin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You instantiate your `ModuleHandler` manually and then call `InitializeModules`, where a catalog is created and passed to a new composition container. Then, this container is used to satisfy all the imports of that particular `ModuleHandler` instance through the line:

```
cc.ComposeParts(this);
```

This tells MEF to look for `Import` attributes and populate the decorated properties with instances of classes decorated with the corresponding `Export` attributes.

What you are missing is the analogous call to populate your `frmTasks` objects. Thus, the following `Import` is not satisfied and the property is `null`:

```
[Import(typeof (Exec.Core.Interfaces.IHost))] 
public Exec.Core.Interfaces.IHost Host;
```

You have several options among which I'd look into the following two:

- Modify the `IModule` interface so that you can explicitly pass an `IHost` to the modules. Then, in the `InitializeModules`, after the call to `ComposeParts`, iterate over the composed modules passing them the host instance. This accounts for setting the `Host` property through the `IModule` interface. You could also stick to the MEF imported property by putting it in the `IModule` interface and calling `ComposeParts` for each module instance.
- Expose the container [through a ServiceLocator](https://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) and get the `IModuleHandler` instance from the modules to access the `Host` property.

Comment: Thanks your comment made me go back and look the IModule Interface again and there was already  was already a call to `IHost Host { get; set; }`  It was being used to set the MdiParent on the form with the value of IHost.   I added `Host = (IHost) this.MdiParent;`  in the Load_Form event  and all was good.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer, I just don't think its the right one.
On my question I edited it and added the main program but i did not add its class.

It looks like

```
namespace Exec
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        //Create a new instance of ModuleHandler. Only one must exist.
        public static ModuleHandler _modHandler = new ModuleHandler();

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            //Initialize the modules. Now the modules will be loaded.
          _modHandler.InitializeModules();


          Application.Run(_modHandler.Host as Form);


        }
    }
}
```

I was debugging and I found that in `_modHandler.InitializeModules();`

IHost Host was set, and its part of

```
public static ModuleHandler _modHandler = new ModuleHandler();
```

and everything here is static but not accessable.   So I changed the class signature to public to make it global (dirty word I know)

```
public static class Program
```

and then in

```
namespace Exec.Modules.Tasks
```

in the Load_Form event I added a line to initialize Host.

```
public partial class frmTasks : Form
{
       [Import(typeof (Exec.Core.Interfaces.IHost))] 
       public Exec.Core.Interfaces.IHost Host;

      private void Load_Form(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Host = Program._modHandler.Host.GetHost; << added this to initialize host

           other stuff....
      }
      other stuff that now works
}
```

I don't think that this is how its supposed to work.   I think that I should be able to populate this through the interfaces and modules...

Comments?